# How can I add buttons to my automatic slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've created an automatic slideshow and I want to know how to add buttons and make it work at the same time than the automatic slideshow. Can anyone help me, please? Here is the code I've written to create the automatic slideshow:

```js
(function() {

  function Slideshow(element) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(element);
    this.init();
  }

  Slideshow.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      this.wrapper = this.el.querySelector(".slider-wrapper");
      this.slides = this.el.querySelectorAll(".slide");
      this.previous = this.el.querySelector(".slider-previous");
      this.next = this.el.querySelector(".slider-next");
      this.index = 0;
      this.total = this.slides.length;
      this.timer = null;

      this.action();
      this.stopStart();
    },
    _slideTo: function(slide) {
      var currentSlide = this.slides[slide];
      currentSlide.style.opacity = 1;

      for (var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
        var slide = this.slides[i];
        if (slide !== currentSlide) {
          slide.style.opacity = 0;
        }
      }
    },
    action: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.timer = setInterval(function() {
        self.index++;
        if (self.index == self.slides.length) {
          self.index = 0;
        }
        self._slideTo(self.index);

      }, 3000);
    },
    stopStart: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.el.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        clearInterval(self.timer);
        self.timer = null;

      }, false);
      self.el.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        self.action();

      }, false);
    }


  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var slider = new Slideshow("#main-slider");

  });


})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

.slider-wrapper>.slide:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="main-slider">
  <!-- outermost container element -->
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <!-- innermost wrapper element -->
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/animals" alt="First" class="slide" style="width:100%" />
    <!-- slides -->
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/business" alt="Second" class="slide" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/city" alt="Third" class="slide" style="width:100%" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to put buttons for what exactly? For previous next feature??

Comment: Yes, @GHOST93..

Comment: One thing I can suggest is that you can have a private method in your JS class which adds the buttons and you can write style for these in CSS, so after rendering they will get styled as per the class coded.

And rest code you need is already given by Hasan in the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the next and prev functions like the example....

```js
(function() {

  function Slideshow(element) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(element);
    this.init();
  }

  Slideshow.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      this.wrapper = this.el.querySelector(".slider-wrapper");
      this.slides = this.el.querySelectorAll(".slide");
      this.previous = this.el.querySelector(".slider-previous");
      this.next = this.el.querySelector(".slider-next");
      this.index = 0;
      this.total = this.slides.length;
      this.timer = null;
      this.nextButton= this.el.querySelector(".next");
      this.prevButton= this.el.querySelector(".prev");

      this.action();
      this.stopStart();
      this.nextSlide();
      this.prevSlide();
    },
    _slideTo: function(slide) {
      var currentSlide = this.slides[slide];
      currentSlide.style.opacity = 1;

      for (var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
        var slide = this.slides[i];
        if (slide !== currentSlide) {
          slide.style.opacity = 0;
        }
      }
    },
    action: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.timer = setInterval(function() {
        self.index++;
        if (self.index == self.slides.length) {
          self.index = 0;
        }
        self._slideTo(self.index);

      }, 3000);
    },
    stopStart: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.el.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        clearInterval(self.timer);
        self.timer = null;

      }, false);
      self.el.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        self.action();

      }, false);
    }
    ,nextSlide:function(){
      var self=this;
      self.nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        clearInterval(self.timer);
        self.timer = null;
        self.index++;
        if (self.index == self.slides.length) {
          self.index = 0;
        }
        self._slideTo(self.index);

      });
    }
    ,prevSlide:function(){
      var self=this;
      self.prevButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        clearInterval(self.timer);
        self.timer = null;
        self.index--;
        if (self.index == -1) {
          self.index = self.slides.length-1;
        }
        
        self._slideTo(self.index);

      });
    }


  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var slider = new Slideshow("#main-slider");

  });


})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

.slider-wrapper>.slide:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
.next{
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
.prev{
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="main-slider">
  <!-- outermost container element -->
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <!-- innermost wrapper element -->
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/animals" alt="First" class="slide" style="width:100%" />
    <!-- slides -->
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/business" alt="Second" class="slide" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/city" alt="Third" class="slide" style="width:100%" />
    <button class='prev'>Prev</button>
    <button class='next'>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

add on click event function on your next & prevues button and for next use the following

```
self._slideTo(self.index);
```

for prevues use this

```
if(self.index+1 == this.slides.length)
self.index = 0 ;
else
self._slideTo(self.index -1);
```